# Adaptive Card inside Teams not returning changes on Input.ChoiceSet on Action.Submit

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

I have a filtering system on my bot.

When I apply the first time, I return the new filters correctly assigned via "default values" on the choice set.

However, when the User applies a new filter, Microsoft teams does not return the selected values, or even the changed ones.

Locally, inside Bot Framework everything works correctly.

On the javascript side I'm sending like this:

```js
await context.sendActivity( {attachments: [CardFactory.adaptiveCard(adaptive_card_to_send)], attachmentLayout: "carousel"});
```

```json
let system_adaptive_card = {
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "body": [
        {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": "New TextBlock",
            "wrap": true,
            "id": "system_text"
        },
        {
            "type": "ColumnSet",
            "columns": [
                {
                    "type": "Column",
                    "width": "stretch",
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "type": "ActionSet",
                            "actions": [
                                {
                                    "type": "Action.Submit",
                                    "title": "  ",
                                    "id": "Thumbs_up",
                                    "tooltip": "Positive Feedback",
                                    "data": {
                                        "action": "FEEDBACK:Like"
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "type": "Action.ToggleVisibility",
                                    "title": "  ",
                                    "targetElements": [
                                        "negative_choice",
                                        "negative_text",
                                        "submit_feedback"
                                    ],
                                    "tooltip": "Negative Feedback"
                                },
                                {
                                    "type": "Action.Submit",
                                    "title": "  ",
                                    "tooltip": "Reset Conversation",
                                    "data": {
                                        "action": "RESET"
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "type": "Action.ToggleVisibility",
                                    "title": "  ",
                                    "targetElements": [
                                        "id_1_button",
                                        "id_2_button",
                                        "id_3_button",
                                        "id_4_button",
                                        {
                                            "elementId": "apply_filter_button",
                                            "isVisible": false
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "elementId": "id_1",
                                            "isVisible": false
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "elementId": "id_2",
                                            "isVisible": false
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "elementId": "id_3",
                                            "isVisible": false
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "elementId": "id_4",
                                            "isVisible": false
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "tooltip": "Filters",
                                    "isVisible": "True"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "style": "emphasis"
        },
        {
            "type": "Input.ChoiceSet",
            "choices": [
                {
                    "title": "Wrong Citation",
                    "value": "Wrong Citation"
                },
                {
                    "title": "Wrong Answer",
                    "value": "Wrong Answer"
                },
                {
                    "title": "Incomplete Answer",
                    "value": "Incomplete Answer"
                },
                {
                    "title": "Other Issue",
                    "value": "Other Issue"
                }
            ],
            "placeholder": "Select A Reason",
            "id": "negative_choice",
            "isVisible": false
        },
        {
            "type": "Input.Text",
            "placeholder": "Explain in More Detail",
            "id": "negative_text",
            "isVisible": false
        },
        {
            "type": "ActionSet",
            "actions": [
                {
                    "type": "Action.Submit",
                    "title": "Send Feedback",
                    "data": {
                        "action": "FEEDBACK:Dislike"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "isVisible": false,
            "id": "submit_feedback"
        },
        {
            "type": "ColumnSet",
            "columns": [
                {
                    "type": "Column",
                    "width": "auto",
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "type": "ActionSet",
                            "actions": [
                                {
                                    "type": "Action.ToggleVisibility",
                                    "title": "id_1",
                                    "targetElements": [
                                        "id_1",
                                        {
                                            "elementId": "apply_filter_button",
                                            "isVisible": true
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            "horizontalAlignment": "Left",
                            "spacing": "None",
                            "isVisible": false,
                            "id": "id_1_button"
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "Input.ChoiceSet",
                            "choices": [
                                {
                                    "title": "1",
                                    "value": "1"
                                },
                                {
                                    "title": "2",
                                    "value": "2"
                                }
                            ],
                            "placeholder": "Placeholder text",
                            "isMultiSelect": true,
                            "id": "id_1",
                            "isVisible": false,
                            "style": "expanded"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "type": "Column",
                    "width": "auto",
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "type": "ActionSet",
                            "actions": [
                                {
                                    "type": "Action.ToggleVisibility",
                                    "title": "id_2",
                                    "targetElements": [
                                        "id_2",
                                        {
                                            "elementId": "apply_filter_button",
                                            "isVisible": true
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            "horizontalAlignment": "Left",
                            "id": "id_2_button",
                            "isVisible": false,
                            "height": "stretch"
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "Input.ChoiceSet",
                            "choices": [
                                {
                                    "title": "1",
                                    "value": "1"
                                },
                                {
                                    "title": "2",
                                    "value": "2"
                                }
                            ],
                            "placeholder": "Placeholder text",
                            "isMultiSelect": true,
                            "spacing": "None",
                            "isVisible": false,
                            "id": "id_2",
                            "style": "expanded"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "type": "Column",
                    "width": "auto",
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "type": "ActionSet",
                            "actions": [
                                {
                                    "type": "Action.ToggleVisibility",
                                    "title": "ID 3",
                                    "targetElements": [
                                        "id_3",
                                        {
                                            "elementId": "apply_filter_button",
                                            "isVisible": true
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            "horizontalAlignment": "Left",
                            "id": "id_3_button",
                            "isVisible": false
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "Input.ChoiceSet",
                            "choices": [
                                {
                                    "title": "1",
                                    "value": "1"
                                },
                                {
                                    "title": "2",
                                    "value": "2"
                                }
                            ],
                            "placeholder": "Placeholder text",
                            "isMultiSelect": true,
                            "isVisible": false,
                            "id": "id_3",
                            "style": "expanded"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "type": "Column",
                    "width": "auto",
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "type": "ActionSet",
                            "actions": [
                                {
                                    "type": "Action.ToggleVisibility",
                                    "title": "ID 4",
                                    "targetElements": [
                                        "id_4",
                                        {
                                            "elementId": "apply_filter_button",
                                            "isVisible": true
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            "horizontalAlignment": "Left",
                            "id": "id_4_button",
                            "isVisible": false
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "Input.ChoiceSet",
                            "choices": [
                                {
                                    "title": "1",
                                    "value": "1"
                                },
                                {
                                    "title": "2",
                                    "value": "2"
                                }
                            ],
                            "placeholder": "Placeholder text",
                            "isMultiSelect": true,
                            "isVisible": false,
                            "id": "id_4",
                            "style": "expanded"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "style": "emphasis",
            "bleed": true
        },
        {
            "type": "ActionSet",
            "actions": [
                {
                    "type": "Action.Submit",
                    "title": "Apply Filter",
                    "data": {
                        "action": "APPLY FILTER",
                        "id_1": "{id_1.value}",
                        "id_2": "{id_2.value}",
                        "id_3": "{id_3.value}",
                        "id_4": "{id_4.value}"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "type": "Action.Submit",
                    "title": "Reset Filter",
                    "data": {
                        "action": "RESET FILTER"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "id": "apply_filter_button",
            "isVisible": false
        }
    ],
    "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
    "version": "1.5"
}
```

Comment: We checked this at our end and when we check  1 & 2 in ID1-https://i.stack.imgur.com/1c572.png, it is returning correct values-https://i.stack.imgur.com/PkaZy.png. We tried the same with reset filter as well, resetting 1 in ID3 - https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUrJa.png,  https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVINd.png

Comment: We can schedule a talk if needed.
Follow the following steps:
1. Select 3 filters and apply.
2. Send a message for the bot to answer.
3. Apply again another filter (or remove one filter).
4. It will random deselect filters.

Comment: So, try with some default values already set and apply filters.
For example:
```json
{
  "type": "Input.ChoiceSet",
  "choices": [
{
  "title": "1",
  "value": "1"
},
{
  "title": "2",
  "value": "2"
}
],
  "placeholder": "Placeholder text",
  "isMultiSelect": true,
  "spacing": "None",
  "isVisible": false,
  "id": "id_2",
  "style": "expanded",
  "value": "1,2"
}
```

Comment: We tried by setting the default values. If we set default values "1,2" for all buttons, Microsoft teams does not return the selected values, or even the changed ones. However if select any 1 value as default it is working fine. Default values - https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRtDk.png. Update filters and click on Apply - https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOrTD.png. Only button2 value is correctly updated - https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9x9v.png. Button 1,2 & 4 values are not returned properly since both values were selected by default. Could you please confirm if you are referring the same issue?

Comment: Basically yes, that is the problem. Teams does not return (sometimes only) the selected values, or changed.